# How do I check if an object on Parse is nil, in Swift?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, null

I'm working on a swift app that allows a user to connect to and disconnect from instagram. Once the user has connected, I store the access token in the PFUser class under a column named instagramCredentials.

```
user["instagramCredentials"] = credentials["access_token"]
user.save()
```

Then if the user wants to disconnect from instagram I remove the access token.

```
user.removeObjectForKey("instagramCredentials")
user.save()
```

When the view loads I want to set a boolean, instagramIsConnected, to false unless there is an access token in instagramCredentials.

```
if user["instagramCredentials"] == nil {
        instagramIsConnected = false
} else {
        instagramIsConnected = true
}
```

but I get an error at runtime

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do something like this, you should learn this format of code. It's the basic of **Swift**:

```
  if let isConnected = user["instagramCredentials"] {
     instagramIsConnected = true
  } else {
     instagramIsConnected = false
  }
```

You can find a topic called "If Statement and Forced Unwrapping" in the **Swift** tutorial from **Apple**.

Answer (score 1):

swift 4 update

```
if (object["instagramCredentials"]) == nil {

//does not exist

} else {

//does exist

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should define user["instagramCredentials"] as optional with a question mark. -> user["instagramCredentials"]?. Only optionals can be nil and than it make sense to check if a value is nil or not.